# Intellij show the current running build

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a spring boot project and using IntelliJ Ultimate Edition (2022.3.2)
I am also using the new UI (beta)

Suppose, that I am starting "customer" microservice (I have a run configuration) by exectuting "spring-boot:run"

Previously, with the community edition, I was always seeing the last started microservice.
If I start customer, then I saw customer, if I start 'invoice' then I saw invoice.

But now, it remains for example at "common data", check the picture.
How can I show always the latest build that I have started?

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Common Data" running when you start "spring-boot:run"?

Comment: @y.bedrov  it does not matter. I always see "common data", also after startup of IntelliJ.

Comment: Could you please check the issue with the latest build?

Comment: @y.bedrov I am already using the latest build. checking for updates does not deliver me any new version.

Comment: Latest version in 2022.3.3 and also there is 2023 EAP.

Comment: @y.bedrov I am using 2022.3.3, so i have the latest build

Comment: Could you please disable custom plugin ("Settings | Plugins | cog wheel | Disable all downloaded plugins")?

Comment: @y.bedrov that did not help unfortunately, I only have 3 plugins though